# What does System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Object) do?

Tags: .net, polymorphism, html-encode

What exactly does [the `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Object)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee360286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do?  Why would there be a method that takes HTML-encodes an object of *any* type?  You would think the documentation would be a little more informative given how vague an operation of that sort would seem to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does the same thing that `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(String)` does except it converts it to a string first.

You can see exactly what it does in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/httpserverutility.cs.html#754712e012a76566)

```
public static String HtmlEncode(object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        // Return null to be consistent with HtmlEncode(string)
        return null;
    }

    var htmlString = value as IHtmlString;
    if (htmlString != null) {
        return htmlString.ToHtmlString();
    }

    return HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
}
```

So first it checks if the object implements `IHtmlString` and calls `ToHtmlString()`, if it does not it calls [`Convert.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131014(v=vs.110).aspx) on the object then uses the string overload of `HtmlEncode` on the converted string to return a result.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I didn't read MSDN closely enough: "Converts **an object's string representation** into an HTML-encoded string"